# Read header after string in Python

Tags: python, text, import-from-csv

I have a few text files and there are multiline headers.  If the file has the string 'Server totals' then I need to read in the text file, columns after this string.

```
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk('z:\\rod\\folder'):
    for name in files:
        with open (currentfile) as d:
            text = d.read()
            for x in text:
                if 'Server Totals' in x:
                    (what do I do now to open the file and read from 'Server Totals' line?)
```

Output from a file should be something like:
Line 50: 'Server Totals'
Line 51: 'Acct No', 'Name', 'Location', 'Desc'....

or it could be something like this:
Line 100: 'Server Totals'
Line 101: 'Acct No', 'Name', 'Location', 'Desc'....

Is this possible?

After the string is found, I need for the Python to begin reading the file after this line and import all of the columns, headers, etc.

Comment: You should illustrate your problem with an example - input, desired output.

Comment: after the line "if 'Server Totals' in x:" Should I input pd.read_csv('filename') ?  Will Python start reading the file at the line it finds the "ServerTotals" string?

Comment: @skuzzy meant we need to see a sample of your input text and how you'd like that sample to appear in your desired output.

Comment: No, it won't. But I have no idea of what your input and output looks like. Provide an example in your post.

Comment: Thanks- just added additoinal information

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution (assuming I understood correctly). However I'm not sure to what extent it is a Pythonic way.
Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd

nrow = 0
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    landmark = 'Kostas'
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'Kostas' in line:
            print(line.index)
            break
        nrow = nrow + 1

csv = pd.read_csv('example.txt', skiprows=nrow+1, delimiter=';')
print(csv)
```

The text file I used was:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sed mauris felis.
Nam eget dictum diam, nec placerat nulla.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Phasellus sollicitudin mi ut posuere blandit.
Donec porttitor ipsum condimentum risus dapibus lobortis.
Kostas Proin ut nibh non mauris pretium hendrerit.
lat;lon;value
32;43;4
33;44;5
34;43;3.2
34;42;5.5
```

The output I get is:

```
   lat  lon  value
0   32   43   4.0
1   33   44   5.0
2   34   43   3.2
3   34   42   5.5
```

Comment: VI. thank you - could you help a little more?   What if the column headers are on multiple lines?  For example, instead of lat, lon, and value on a single line.... what if the header was on multiple lines, such as,                         lat   lon   value                                                                                                                        /n                                               aii   iyi     usd

Comment: @belewis6i Hi, can you give a clear example of headers and data?